# How to get each individual tree's prediction in LightGBM?

Tags: python, random-forest, decision-tree, lightgbm

I am using [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with Python for a multi-class classification problem. I would like to know the individual prediction of each tree. However, I haven't succeeded yet. Could you show me how to access the prediction of each tree for a given test sample please? My final goal is to understand how LGBMClassifier.predict_proba estimates class probabilities.

Comment: you can dump all the individual trees but I'm not sure it's possible to get predictions from each tree.

Answer (score 0):

For a LightGBM model, each tree's leaves contain raw values in the units of the objective function, and leaf values are summed to produce a prediction.

LightGBM's `predict()` API allows you to customize which iterations' trees are used.

Here's an example in Python showing how to get predictions from a LightGBM model as of:

- all trees *up to a given iteration*
- all trees *from a specific iteration*

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=10_000, centers=3)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)

bst = lgb.train(
    train_set=dtrain,
    params={
        "objective": "multiclass",
        "num_class": 3,
        "num_leaves": 7
    },
    num_boost_round=10
)

# get predictions using all trees up to the 5th tree
preds_first5 = bst.predict(
    X, num_iteration=5, raw_score=True
)

# get predictions using all trees up to the 6th tree
preds_first6 = bst.predict(
    X, num_iteration=6, raw_score=True
)

# get predictions from exactly the 6th tree
preds_tree6 = bst.predict(
    X, start_iteration=5, num_iteration=1, raw_score=True
)

# confirm that those things are consistent
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    actual=preds_tree6,
    desired=preds_first6 - preds_first5,
    rtol=1e-10
)
```

Note that for multiclass classification, for each iteration of boosting, LightGBM trains 1 tree per class. Try the following with the model trained in the example above.

```py
# 30 trees (3 classes * 10 iterations)
assert bst.num_trees() == 30
```

LightGBM's `predict()` API is configurable in terms of *iterations*, not trees. For multiclass classification, it returns an array of shape `[num_data, num_classes]`, where element `[i, j]` is the predicted probability that the `i`th sample in the data belongs to the `j`th class.

```py
bst.predict(X, start_iteration=5, num_iteration=1)
```

```
array([[0.37597866, 0.31173329, 0.31228805],
       [0.37597866, 0.31173329, 0.31228805],
       [0.37597866, 0.31173329, 0.31228805],
       ...])
```

If you truly want to see the predictions from one *tree* for a multiclass classification model, using the `lightgbm` Python package, install `pandas` and dump the model to a DataFrame.

```py
model_df = bst.trees_to_dataframe()

# dump the structure of exactly the 6th tree
model_df[model_df["tree_index"] == 5].head(50)
```

|  | tree_index | node_depth | node_index | left_child | right_child | parent_index | split_feature | split_gain | threshold | decision_type | missing_direction | missing_type | value | weight | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | 5 | 1 | 5-S0 | 5-L0 | 5-S1 |  | Column_1 | 1344.09 | -3.43421 | <= | left | None | 0 | 0 | 10000 |
| 66 | 5 | 2 | 5-L0 |  |  | 5-S0 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | -0.0938297 | 1043.4 | 3320 |
| 67 | 5 | 2 | 5-S1 | 5-S2 | 5-S4 | 5-S0 | Column_1 | 3407.11 | 1.3275 | <= | left | None | 0.0434366 | 2255.11 | 6680 |
| 68 | 5 | 3 | 5-S2 | 5-L1 | 5-S3 | 5-S1 | Column_1 | 40.5453 | 0.785617 | <= | left | None | 0.157656 | 1210.15 | 3365 |
| 69 | 5 | 4 | 5-L1 |  |  | 5-S2 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.162107 | 1142.59 | 3170 |
| 70 | 5 | 4 | 5-S3 | 5-L3 | 5-L4 | 5-S2 | Column_0 | 41.9748 | -3.34207 | <= | left | None | 0.0823763 | 67.5516 | 195 |
| 71 | 5 | 5 | 5-L3 |  |  | 5-S3 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | -0.00831109 | 29.0726 | 87 |
| 72 | 5 | 5 | 5-L4 |  |  | 5-S3 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.150895 | 38.479 | 108 |
| 73 | 5 | 3 | 5-S4 | 5-S5 | 5-L5 | 5-S1 | Column_1 | 28.1422 | 1.96724 | <= | left | None | -0.0888383 | 1044.96 | 3315 |
| 74 | 5 | 4 | 5-S5 | 5-L2 | 5-L6 | 5-S4 | Column_0 | 39.4162 | -2.79966 | <= | left | None | -0.0346315 | 87.7335 | 273 |
| 75 | 5 | 5 | 5-L2 |  |  | 5-S5 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | -0.0628375 | 74.5347 | 234 |
| 76 | 5 | 5 | 5-L6 |  |  | 5-S5 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | 0.124651 | 13.1987 | 39 |
| 77 | 5 | 4 | 5-L5 |  |  | 5-S4 |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | -0.0938066 | 957.229 | 3042 |

The predicted values will be from one of the leaf nodes (rows where `node_index` has an `L` in it). You'll have to work through the tree's rules to figure out which leaf a sample falls into.